# Mapbox heatmap in Android depending on Features properties

Tags: android, colors, properties, heatmap, mapbox-android

I am trying to display the contamination at different points using a mapbox heatmap in android. However, I don´t know how to set the heatmap color different than by heatmapDensity().

I have tried this, but it doesn´t work

```
       layer.setProperties(
            heatmapColor(
                  interpolate(
                          linear(), get("pm"),
                           stop(0, color(Color.GREEN)),
                           stop(20, color(Color.YELLOW)),
                           stop(40, color(Color.RED))
                  )
            )
       );
```

Is there anyway I could display my info based on a feature property rather than by its density?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

The Maps SDK also has `heatmapWeight`, `heatmapIntensity`, `heatmapRadius`, and `heatmapOpacity`.

See the following Mapbox demo app examples to see your heatmap styling options:

- https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/display-a-heatmap
- https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/add-multiple-heatmap-styles

> Is there anyway I could display my info based on a feature property rather than by its density?

Yes, https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/display-a-heatmap shows how to do this. The weight is based on [the earthquake magnitude number found as a property in each feature](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/earthquakes.geojson).

```
heatmapWeight(
    interpolate(
      linear(), get("mag"),
      stop(0, 0),
      stop(6, 1)
    )
)
```